# Express not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, express, url-routing

I am trying to set up a react app with express running. However, I can't understand why it won't load the page I want it to

this is my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
});

app.get('/canYouPlay.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('/canYouPlay.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

This works. however if I change the first app.get to:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./canYouPLay.html');
});
```

It still renders the same HTML file even when restarting the app even though they are different files.

also when i run this function:

```
  handleClick: function() {
    document.location.replace('./canYouPlay');
},
```

it says it cannot get /canYouPLay even though a HTML and js file exist with that name.

what have I missed or doing wrong?

Comment: Can you list your folder structure? i.e. where did you place the html and js files? Same level as your app.js? Anything in public?

Comment: public contains index.js
other than that, all files are on the same level as each other. the only folder is public. @kentoh

Comment: is canYouPlay.html inside public folder?

Comment: no it is not but i thought that the public folder was self generated when webpack bundles everything together? @WitVault

Comment: It dependes on your webpack what are you generating e.g only bundle.js or index.html or css using extract plugins.